# How to cast date Strings to DateTime format with extended parsing in ClickHouse?

Tags: casting, clickhouse

I have a String field with timestamp like this: "2020-01-13T07:34:25.804445Z". And i want to parse it to datetime (to use in Grafana filters, for example). But i getting this error:

```
SELECT SELECT "@timestamp" AS timestamp, CAST(timestamp AS DateTime) as datetime from table

Cannot parse string '2020-01-13T06:55:05.704Z' as DateTime: syntax error at position 19 (parsed just '2020-01-13T06:55:05').
```

I found variable [date_time_input_format on documentation](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-date_time_input_format) which "allows extended parsing". But it says that this setting doesn't apply to date and time functions. So how do i cast string date with timezone to DateTime?

Comment: Actually, this "date_time_input_format" allows me to declare fields ad DateTime and add my "extended" timestamps into it directly without casting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT parseDateTimeBestEffortOrNull('2020-01-13T07:34:25.804445Z')

┌─parseDateTimeBestEffortOrNull('2020-01-13T07:34:25.804445Z')─┐
│                                          2020-01-13 07:34:25 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/type_conversion_functions/#type_conversion_functions-parsedatetimebesteffort